# Controller action is not working but controller is working

Tags: php, yii2

I have created new controller called AuthContoller in yii2. But the controller action is not working. Can you check in controller what I am doing wrong?

Controller

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

/**
 * Site controller
*/
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action){
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)){
            if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){  
                return $this->redirect('home/');
            }
        }
    }


    public function actionLogin(){    
        echo 'I am here'; exit;    
        $this->layout = false;
        return $this->render('login');
    }

}
```

Nothing in the view

[image]

Comment: Check your Route first

Comment: Don't post code as images. All relevant code must be copy/pasted into the question itself.

Comment: It seems you have an error , please add  'ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);' to index.php and report the result

Answer (score 0):

According to Yii2 documentation, the function must return an `true` or `false` value.
Adding `return true;` will solve your problem.

[yii2 `beforeAction()` doc:](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#beforeAction()-detail)

> The method will trigger the `EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION` event. The return value of the method will determine whether the action should continue to run.

your code should look like the following:

```
public function beforeAction($action){
  // your custom code here, if you want the code to run before action filters,
  // which are triggered on the [[EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION]] event, e.g. PageCache or AccessControl

   if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
       return false;
   }

   if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
       return $this->redirect('home/');
   }
   // other custom code here

   return true; // or false to not run the action
}
```